# How can I create a patch that spans commits using Sourcetree?

Tags: git, patch, atlassian-sourcetree

I observe that when I "Create a patch", the dialog creates the patch that is "to" the commit I selected "from" it's predecessor.

In the dialog, I can tantalisingly select two separate commits and the diff panel shows the diffs that are between those two - that's the patch that I want.

But when I press "OK", I still get the single commit patch.

Is there some way to achieve what I meant, using Sourcetree?

(note: it might be nice to have a "sourcetree" tag?)

Comment: git does not have any dialog boxes - what else are you using?

Comment: As I said "Sourcetree".   The git GUI client for Macs from Atlassian (who make jira etc).

Answer (score 5):

You could use `git diff oldHash..newHash > file.patch` command to get single patch for multiple commits.

Comment: Thanks!  It's good to know the commandline way to do it, and it's probably easy enough to do it that way.

I was really asking "how to do it in Sourcetree?"